# Blender cycles texture flickering issue when rendering unique simple solid

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm trying to create a simple animation in cycles where a simple glass tetrahedron is lit by a lamp spin on it's Z axis. The tetrahedron was generated using the "add mesh: extra objects" add on. It is made of glass by assigning it's transmission to 0.8

Everything looks as I want when I render single images, but when I render it as an animation the surface of the tetrahedron is flickering in a random way. Any ideas on what to do to fix this ?

These are the only things I have in my scene, all the rest has been purged. Also, this only seems to be a problem for a "glass" material, as this doesn't happen with a metal material

[image]

Comment: Please share your file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com (copy&paste given code into your Q). Thank you

Comment: @vklidu there's the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a double surface issue. you made the object in edit mode I presume. and 2 times!
ALWAYS check for face orientations:
[image]

quick fix:
on edit mode, select all with A then press M and merge distance.
and recalculate your normal after that:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/normals.html#recalculate

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I have no idea how it occured though...